# how to avoid excessive and unnecessary db connections in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

In popular PHP framework CodeIgniter we usually make excessive and unnecessary db connections like this(basically in use master-slave mode so I can't use CI's autoload of database):

I have a subclass of CI_Model

```
class MY_Model extends CI_Model
{
    $this->db_write = null;
    $this->db_read = null;
    public function __construct()
    {
        if(empty($this->db_write) || empty($this->db_read)) {
            $this->db_write = $this->load->database('master', true);
            $this->db_read  = $this->load->database('slave', true);
         }
    }
}
```

}

and other models inherit from this MY_Model like

```
class User_Model extends MY_Model
{
    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model(other_model);
    }
}
```

but I found every time I loaded a model in controller or loaded other models inside a model, it would
execute MY_Model's construct function, so it can make a lot of waste db connections, it's so terrible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

then I looked CI's function to autoload database, and I found a resolution of this problem.

```
class MY_Model extends CI_Model
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $CI = &get_instance();
        if(empty($CI->db_write) || empty($CI->db_read)) {
            $CI->db_write = $this->load->database('master', true);
            $CI->db_read  = $this->load->database('slave', true);
        }
    }
}
```

`$CI = &get_instance` will get the quote of CI controller's instance, and I assign master and slave connection object to it's property `db_write` and `db_read`, because this instance is globally effective
so this way can avoid unnecessary db connections.

and cause CI_Model's magic function __get

```
function __get($key)
{
    $CI =& get_instance();
    return $CI->$key;
}
```

We can access these two properties I declared over here through $this->db_write and $this->db_read.
Wish this post make you relax who also encounter this problem, and if anyone has other ways to resolve this problem, please comment in this post and I'am 
happy to learn your resolution :)

Answer (score -3):

You can use

```
    $this->db->close();
```

after getting the data and to reconnect you may use

```
    $this->db->reconnect();
```

U can refer to this [page](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/connecting.html)